# Is "Devilman: Crybaby" related to the 90's or the older Devilman series?

Tags: devilman, devilman-crybaby

I looked at MyAnimeList, there is a classic series, it's Devilman, had an anime adaptation in January 5th, 2018. I am interested to watching this series. Quick search for these series, it has a lot of adaptations since 1970's.

Do I have to watch all of those serieses before started to watch *Devilman: Crybaby*? Are these series unrelated to the past series?

Note: I have never watched or tried to watch this series, so I have no idea about this franchise.

Comment: I've never seen it nor devilman, but everything I've seen about devilman crybaby says it's a modernized retelling of the devilman manga, so it probably stands on its own.

Comment: Your title and question are distinctly different. do you want to know if the series are related, or if there are any of them you need to see before watching Crybaby? This confusion led to two opposite answers that each are at least partially correct

Comment: @JesseBarnett i mean, i wabt to know if there are any of devilman series that i need to watch before i started watching crybaby

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes

Devilman Crybaby roughly follows the plot of the original devilman manga (1972) which started the [Devilman Franchise](http://devilman.wikia.com/wiki/Devilman_(Franchise)) where there are sequels, prequels, remakes, new plot lines, crossovers ect... Essentially a continual flow of new content from the 70's to date, see the above link for details on which series fit where.

*EDIT: Just commenting on the other answer saying No. My answer was really intended to respond to the title of those works being **related** where it seems you are responding specifically to if OP should watch something else first. While I agree Devilman Crybaby stands on its own as a story and there is no content that is **necessary** to see before or after watching... There are plenty of story connections to be found other works such as the manga titled "Devilman Shin" and "Devilman Lady" which are official sequels, or the prequel "Demon Knight"*

Comment: Which devilman should i watch first ? Is it devilman original ? Or devilman:seriesz or ddevilman: bla bla bla?

Comment: "Devilman Crybaby roughly follows the plot of the original devilman manga" so I recommend you watch Devilman Crybaby first

Answer (score 2):

**No**

You don't need to watch any of the older series to watch crybaby. Crybaby is the main story from start to finish which follows the main Devilman manga. It has no storyline connections to the other series.

Comment: any link/references  ?